# flask mail works in interpreter, but not app

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

Ok, I'm using Miguel Grinberg's Flask Mega Tutorial (which is awesome by the way!) as a basis for this.  If I run this in the python interpreter it works fine, but when I submit the form in the web app, I get no error messages, but the message does not send.  Code of my app.py below.  Thanks in advance!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask_mail import Message, Mail
from packages.decorators import async

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'dummy_key'

app.config["MAIL SERVER"] = "mail.domainname.com"
app.config["MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND"] = False
app.config["TESTING"] = False
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 26
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'webmaster@domainname.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'password'

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def static_page(page_name):
        return render_template('%s.html' % page_name)

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
        form=ContactForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':
                if form.validate() == False:
                        flash('All fields are required.')
                        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
                else:
                        msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='webmaster@domainname.com', recipients=['admin@domainname.com'])
                        msg.body = """
                        From: %s %s <%s>
                        %s
                        """ % (form.firstName.data, form.lastName.data, form.email.data, form.comment.data)

                        @async
                        def send_async_email(app, msg):
                                with app.app_context():
                                        mail.send(msg)

                        send_async_email(app, msg)

                        return 'Form posted.'

        elif request.method == 'GET':
                return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

So after I submit the form I see "form posted", but never receive an email. The only thing I do differently in the interpreter is I manually fill out the msg variable with strings instead of receiving input from the form fields.

Edit:  below is what is in packages.decorators

```
from threading import Thread

def async(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thr = Thread(target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thr.start()
    return wrapper
```

Comment: What's that `async` decorator?

Comment: I'm not too clear on how this works and am still reading on this, but it comes from https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xi-email-support.  Basically adds threading module.  See below.

Comment: from threading import Thread

    def async(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            thr = Thread(target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            thr.start()
        return wrapper

Comment: Code in comment is not readable, add it to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Just added.  Thanks!

Comment: Threading in web apps is a bad idea, remove the decorator and it will work.

Comment: Ok.  I removed the decorator and it gives me an internal server error.  If I look in the console it's error 500.  If I look in the terminal window running the app.py, it says Errno 111 connection refused.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The your mail seting are wrong or there is a network problem.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it works in the interpreter.

Comment: As @KlausD. said, make it work without multi-threading first. If its showing error 500, add `app.debug = True` before the `app.run()` statement temporarily to view the complete error message in the browser.

Comment: with debugging on, it gives a socket error no 111 connection refused.

Comment: Are you changing any of the settings when you are running this from the console? Something like: `$ export MAIL_SERVER="something_else"` or entirely a different config file like: `$ export APP_SETTINGS=config.DevConfig`